# Linkedin SDK You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I created an application in linkedin developers and set OAuth 2.0 redirect urls as `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/myProject/`. Then I wrote `<script>` in `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 86g3tbk6gy0y56
    onLoad: liLogin()
    authorize: yes
</script>
```

Also I wrote one more `<script>` at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
    var liLogin = function() { 
        IN.UI.Authorize().params({"scope":["r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress"]}).place();
        IN.Event.on(IN, 'auth', getProfileData);
    }

    var getProfileData = function() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id,firstName,lastName,email-address,picture-urls::(original),public-profile-url,location:(name)").result(function (me) {
            var profile = me.values[0];
            var id = profile.id;
            var firstName = profile.firstName;
            var lastName = profile.lastName;
            var emailAddress = profile.emailAddress;
            var pictureUrl = profile.pictureUrls.values[0];
            var profileUrl = profile.publicProfileUrl;
            var country = profile.location.name;
            alert(firstName + " " + lastName);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then I create an `<a>` tag for calling the `liLogin` function.

`<a onClick="liLogin()">Linkedin</a>`

> Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of > this key's configuration.
>      at userspace?v=0.0.2000-RC8.60429-
>   1429&apiKey=86g3vbk6gy0y56&onLoad=liLogin()&authorize=yes&secure=1&:22
>      at userspace?v=0.0.2000-RC8.60429-
>   1429&apiKey=86g3vbk6gy0y56&onLoad=liLogin()&authorize=yes&secure=1&:31

Above error occurs when I run the application.

Also, if I write configuration with `""`, then linkedin login page appears, but the content is `uh oh`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    'api_key': '86g3tbk6gy0y56',
    'onLoad': 'liLogin()',
    'authorize': 'yes'
</script>
```

How can I make linkedin configuration?

Comment: Do not use quotes on properties. The callback function should be only `liLogin` without `()`. Your API key should be the `client id` key. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason LinkedIn does not recognize "localhost" as a valid redirect URI.
So I suggest you use the actual domain name when you test your website in dev environment.
Just add the following line to your host file:

```
127.0.0.1    YOUR SITE DOMAIN
```